# Create custom post slider using slick

Tags: javascript, wordpress, carousel, slick.js

I have been trying to create a recent post slider using slick-slider for my wordpress page. I want to be able to add the slider into elementor by using a shortcode. I don't have a lot of experience in coding. So I am not sure where I am going wrong. I managed to compose the following piece of coding based on some examples that I found online and I added the javascript file using a custom js plugin for wordpress. I obviously have done something wrong, because if I activate this file, elementor will not load because of a critical error. I have been trying to create custom post slider for a while now without any success. I would really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

```
//Enqueue Slick
function add_slick() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'slider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/slick.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'slider-theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/slick-theme.css');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick.min.js');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_slick' );

//Build Shortcode to Loop Over Testimonials
function recentpost_loop_func( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
    ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <div class="recentpost-slider">
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="single-post">
                <a class="single-post-image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                <a class="single-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
};

add_shortcode( 'recentpostSlider', 'recentpost_loop_func' ); 


//Initiliaze Slick

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.recentpost-slider').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: 50px,
  });
});
```